# Get first word after substring in string

Tags: python

Hi I'm trying to get the word after a specified sub string, like...

```
str = Quote from: Bob1 ...
```

I'm trying to search for everytime Quote from: appears and get the word after, in this case Bob1.

I've tried:

```
print((re.findall(r'Quote from:\a\X\\9', str)))
```

But it just returns `[]`.

Comment: What are you expecting `\a\X\\9` to match?

Comment: @jonrsharpe The first word which can be alphanumeric, it'll be this pattern which is wrong but I'm not sure how to fix it

Comment: Well you could start by reading about how regex patterns work, rather than making a seemingly-random guess. For example https://docs.python.org/3/howto/regex.html

Comment: *"`Quote from:` matches the characters Quote from: literally (case sensitive)
`\a` matches the bell character (ASCII 7)
`\X` matches the character X literally (case sensitive)
`\\` matches the character \ literally
`9` matches the character 9 literally"* - probably **not** what you wanted. https://regex101.com/r/kS7yA3/1

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This should work for you, using `split`.

```
>>> str = "Quote from: Bob1 ..."
>>> str.split("Quote from:")[1].split()[0]
'Bob1'
```

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly and without regex! Will mark as answered after time limit expires.

Comment: Also easily morphed into the case where you have multiple "Quote from:" instances where you want to find the following word: `[frag.split()[0] for frag in str.split("Quote from:")[1:]]`

Comment: Also 7 times faster than mine. +1

Comment: How can I do the same for a column in a data frame?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

s = 'Quote from: Bob1 ...'
re.sub(r'Quote from: (\S+).*', r'\1', s)

'Bob1'
```